# Saving a picture from a webcam displayed video in a PictureBox in VB6

Tags: vb6, video-capture, picturebox

I have used a code from the internet to show my webcam in a certain form, however, i dont know how to capture an image and save it automatically to my local disk drive via command button click. would anyone help me ASAP :))
here is my code for the form.

```
    Option Explicit
Const ws_visible = &H10000000
Const ws_child = &H40000000
Const WM_USER = 1024
Const WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY = WM_USER + 30
Const wm_cap_driver_connect = WM_USER + 10
Const wm_cap_set_preview = WM_USER + 50
Const wm_cap_set_overlay = WM_USER + 51
Const WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE = WM_USER + 52
Const WM_CAP_SEQUENCE = WM_USER + 62
Const WM_CAP_SINGLE_FRAME_OPEN = WM_USER + 70
Const WM_CAP_SINGLE_FRAME_CLOSE = WM_USER + 71
Const WM_CAP_SINGLE_FRAME = WM_USER + 72
Const DRV_USER = &H4000
Const DVM_DIALOG = DRV_USER + 100
Const PREVIEWRATE = 30
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function capCreateCaptureWindow Lib "avicap32.dll" Alias "capCreateCaptureWindowA" (ByVal a As String, ByVal b As Long, ByVal c As Integer, ByVal d As Integer, ByVal e As Integer, ByVal f As Integer, ByVal g As Long, ByVal h As Integer) As Long

Dim hwndc As Long
Dim saveflag As Integer
Dim pictureindex As Integer
Dim filter1(-1 To 1, -1 To 1) As Single
Dim filter2(-1 To 1, -1 To 1) As Single
Dim temp As String

Private Sub Command2_Click()
Unload Me
Main.Show
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo handler:
hwndc = capCreateCaptureWindow("CaptureWindow", ws_child Or ws_visible, 0, 0,     Pichwnd.Width, Pichwnd.Height, Pichwnd.hWnd, 0)
If (hwndc <> 0) Then
    temp = SendMessage(hwndc, wm_cap_driver_connect, 0, 0)
    temp = SendMessage(hwndc, wm_cap_set_preview, 1, 0)
    temp = SendMessage(hwndc, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, PREVIEWRATE, 0)

    temp = SendMessage(Me.hWnd, WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY, 1, 0)
    Picture1.Picture = Clipboard.GetData
Else
    MsgBox "Unable to capture video.", vbCritical
End If
Exit Sub
handler:
End
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Initialize()
If Me.WindowState <> vbMaximized Then
    Me.WindowState = vbMaximized
Else
    Me.WindowState = vbNormal
End If
End Sub
```

my code might be too long but i just learned some vb6 via tutorials as i need to make a GUI to my Grad project. Finally thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Send the [`WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743900%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) message to your `hwndc` with the filename to save to.

A better option is to handle the video callbacks yourself with [`WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_FRAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743921%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) message or the [`capVideoStreamCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd797759%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) callback function.

Also, take a look at the examples at http://www.shrinkwrapvb.com/videocap.htm.

Note that VfW capture is very outdated and should be replaced with Directshow (but is very difficult to do properly in VB6)

Comment: Isn't DirectShow also being phased out?  I was fairly sure this process began in Vista

Comment: I've not seen any huge effort to. AFAIK, it's still central to most media applications.

Comment: "Microsoft plans to completely replace DirectShow gradually with Media Foundation in future Windows versions. As described in the Media Foundation article, Windows Vista and Windows 7 applications use Media Foundation instead of DirectShow for several media related tasks." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectShow